# List item add to first place and remove last element with Jquery

Tags: jquery, list, addition

today i ran into a problem with lists and Jquery. I have a list with 4 element. It's generated dynamically from a database and refresh the database every x seconds. When i have a new record i want to remove the last list item (this works) and add a new item to the top of the list with some fancy effect and flash it 4 or 5 times.
Actually i have a working code but i think it cuold be done better. My question is what is the best solution to do this?

Here is the code:

```
 $( document ).ready(function() {
$.fn.fadeInNext = function(delay) {
    return $(this).fadeIn(delay,function() {
        $(this).next().fadeInNext();
    });
};

$('li').hide().fadeInNext(1500);
$('li').last().remove();
$('li:eq(0)').before("<li>New item</li>").fadeIn(1500);
});
```

Thank you for your answers!

Regards,
Gábor

Comment: Could you share your attempt

Comment: Sure :) I added to the original post.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/oyzq21rr/) would be nice i guess

```
$(function(){
    var ul = $('.list-group');
    var li = ul.find('li').last().clone();
    ul.prepend(li);
    li.stop()
        .css('backgroundColor','#FAA523')
        .animate({"backgroundColor": "white"},1500);
});
```

NOTE: this has a plugin [dependency](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color). So make sure you include that.